# Как определить текущий язык ОС?

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать программу мультиязычной. Мне нужно узнать, какой язык в ОС.

Предполагаю, что здесь копать `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`.

Есть ли неплохой вариант для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture
```

[ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.installeduiculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Такой момент, в данном случае я получу не текущий язык ОС. К примеру. Родной язык русский, а я поставил языковой пакет польский. И использую польский язык. Текущий язык - польский, но не русский. А ваш ответ даст мне всегда русский, независимо от языкового пакета.